# Unmarshalling a Socket's InputStream closes the Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, xml-serialization, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a server-client architecture where the client sends an XML to the server who reads it and generates a PDF out of it and sends that back to the client.

On the client side:

```
JAXBElement<Xml> xml = ...
Socket sock = ...
Marshaller marshaller = ...
marshaller.marshal(xml, sock.getOutputStream());
sock.shutdownOuput();
```

Meanwhile on the server side:

```
ServerSocket server = ...
Socket client = server.accept();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ...
// client.isClosed() -> false
JAXBElement<Xml> xml =
  (JAXBElement<Xml>)) unmarshaller.unmarshall(client.getInputStream());
// client.isClosed() -> true
Pdf pdf = new Pdf(xml);
client.getOutputStream().write(pdf.toBytes());
// "socket is closed" IOException is thrown
```

If I don't unmarshall the client's `InputStream` (on the server side) and just send back a dummy PDF then everything's goes smoothly. So, I have to assume that the `Unmarshaller` closes the `InputStream` it is given, thus implicitly closing the client `Socket` ruining my day...

Any idea on solving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class XMLEntityManager calls close on the InputStream.

You can use a [FilterInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) to avoid a close() call of the underlying stream.

Subclass FilterInputStream and override the close() method with an empty body:

```
public class MyInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
  public MyInputStream(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
  }

  @Override 
  public void close() {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Then change your unmarshall() call to

```
JAXBElement<Xml> xml =
    (JAXBElement<Xml>)) unmarshaller.unmarshall(new MyInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
```

So the JAXB framework still calls close() on the stream, but it's now filtered out by your own stream instance and the socket stream remains open.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to explicitly override an InputStream in your code like vanje suggest, [Apache commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/io/) provide a implementation that acheive this:

take a look at  :

[CloseShieldInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html)